# Can this PHP Script be killed?

Tags: php, destructor

```
<?php

class Test {

    public function foo() {
        echo "Foo!";
        die();
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        header('location: http://google.com');
    }

}

$Test = new Test;
$Test->foo();
```

I have a class which simply assign's various Session variables then pings the user back to their previous script. I figured that it would be simpler to have a single redirect on the destruct instead of 10 lines saying the same thing.

I later found a bug in my script and found out that it was nigh on unkillable. For future reference, is there anyway to kill this script  or will it always redirect?

To clarify, the script always redirects even with die(), exit in the foo function.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236795/php-destructor-vs-register-shutdown-function/236830#236830

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Test` object is destructed when a browser disconnects: it won't redirect just because the browser won't receive the header! However, if you explicitly `unset($Test);`, it will

**UPD**: I'm wrong: the script will call all destructors with the browser still connected. However, I wouldn't rely on that

Comment: The script always redirects. I would have thought the expected action above would be for it to half after printing Foo

Comment: @JasonS: The redirect can still occur if output buffering is turned on. There's a [setting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) for that in php.ini; maybe that's on here?